# Volley response string not working

Tags: php, android, regex

I tried to get response but response are shown in `public void onResponse(String response)` response variable.When i parse variable from jsonobject .its not show anything.

private void requestData(String uri) {

```
    user = username.getText().toString();
     pass = password.getText().toString();

     RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("status");

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }               

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString()+"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("User_Name", user);  
                params.put("Password", pass);

                return params;
        }
    };

        queue.add(myReq);       
}
```

In the Web browser php json response are show:

����������{"status":true,"message":"user are login."}

php code is:

function logedin_post(){

```
    $username = $this->input->post('User_Name');
    $password = $this->input->post('Password');
    $check_username = $this->validate_username($username);
    if($check_username==TRUE){
        $check_password = $this->validate_password($password,$username);
        if($check_password==TRUE){              
            $row = $this->common_model->getRecord('*','users','User_Name',$username)->result_array();               
            $sess_array = array(
                'User_ID'=>$row[0]['User_ID'],
                'User_Name'=>$row[0]['User_Name'],
                'User_Role'=>$row[0]['User_Role'],

            );      
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', $sess_array);
            $this->response(array(
                'status'=>true,
                'message'=>'user are login.'
                ));
        }else{

                            $this->response(array(
                'status'=>false,
                'message'=>'Please enter your correct Password.'
                ));
        }
    }else{

                    $this->response(array(
                'status'=>false,
                'message'=>'Please enter your correct Username.'
                ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the POST Params are being sended in the request, if u are not getting any response, it could be that the PHP file is getting an error and u have error_reporting(0) and its showing a blank page, try error_reporting(E_ALL) into the php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use

```
 try {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject data = obj.getBoolean("status");

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it seems the web response have some encoding problem